# How to stop PreferenceFragment setting Settings into default SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an PreferenceFragment and when the user changes specified Preferences than I want to check if the permissions are granted. Otherwise I want to cancel the Preference Set.

My PreferenceFragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
    preferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesName("com.******.*******.mainSettings");
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main_preferences, rootKey);
    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_SettingsFragment);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    switch (key) {
        case "usesBiometricStart": {
            if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,false)) {
                FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
                assert fingerprintManager != null;
                if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(Objects.requireNonNull(getView()), R.string.object_no_fingerprint_permission, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.setBackgroundTint(getActivity().getColor(R.color.black_50));
                    TextView textView = snackbar.getView().findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setMaxLines(5);
                    snackbar.show();
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key,false).apply();
                    return;
                }

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(Objects.requireNonNull(getView()), R.string.object_no_fingerprint_permission, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.setBackgroundTint(getActivity().getColor(R.color.black_50));
                    TextView textView = snackbar.getView().findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setMaxLines(5);
                    snackbar.show();
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key,false).apply();
                    return;
                }

                if (fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(Objects.requireNonNull(getView()), R.string.object_enrolled_finger_needed, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.setBackgroundTint(getActivity().getColor(R.color.black_50));
                    TextView textView = snackbar.getView().findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setMaxLines(5);
                    snackbar.show();
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key,false).apply();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

but I don't know why

> Edit

`sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key,false).apply();` this line works but doesn't change the switchproperty on runtime. That means if I set it true. The property will resaved as false and than I reopen the fragment it is also false.

So my actuall question how to change the value of the switchPreference onRunntime programaticly.

Comment: Oh thank you Igor F. didn't see that

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Chances are, the switch statements are wrong.

Comment: Yes I have thried this and than I edited the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is using `((SwitchPreference)findPreference("<preferencekey>")).setChecked(<bool>)`

That's it
Happy coding